# How can I handle errors in Vagrantfile?

Tags: vagrantfile

I have this code in Vagrantfile:

```
begin
   ...
   vb.customize ... my Ruby code goes here
   ...
rescue
   puts "my error message goes here in case of Ruby error"
end        
# Ruby code below should be executed even in case of error, however instead it exits
... never executed in case of error
```

I was hoping that standard Ruby error handling block will work here.
What am I missing?